# Odoo 8 : Limit access to graph view using security group

Tags: xml, odoo-8

I am trying to limit access to the **purchase.order** graph view using groups. I have created a group and added it to the view with **groups_id** field. After having updated the module, it has added correctly the group to the view and the view to the group, but I still can access the view even though the current user is not a member of the group.

My main goal is to give access to that view only to a limited number of users without having to create another action window an menu.

Can anyone help?